# is there other program to make ubuntu apps besides quickly?

Tags: software-recommendation, application-development, quickly, development

And in some other programming language maybe?i was wondering if i can create an app in some other program not quickly and post in in the ubuntu store?

Comment: what language where you thinking about?

Answer (score 2):

You can choose whatever you want. Quickly is just a set of templates and commands that start standalone programs.

I do all my programming with Gedit, Glade and the GNOME Terminal. But you could replace Gedit with any other texteditor or even a bit more of a IDE, like Geany or Eclipse (among many others). Maybe even Anjuta is an option, it has embedded Glade.

It all depends on with what tools you feel comfortable, not someone else. That's why you should test and try different setups to see what fits your needs, not what someone else tells you is the "best" solution.

Comment: Okay so i can use other programing language

Comment: Yes. It basicly comes to this: you can use nearly whatever you want.